# Which Times-like package provides better typesetting for text and math?

Tags: fonts, newtx, times, stix

I am using `libertine` and `newtxmath` packages in my document for typesetting by `pdflatex`. The following code shows the fonts setup.

```
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
%
\usepackage[oldstyle,semibold,type1]{libertine}% Linux Libertine font
\usepackage{textcomp}% Required to get special symbols
\usepackage[lf,semibold]{MyriadPro}% Sans Serif font
\usepackage[scaled=.85]{beramono}% Typewriter font 
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,amsthm} % AMS packages    
\usepackage[libertine,cmintegrals,cmbraces,vvarbb]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[scr=boondoxo]{mathalfa}% Extra math symbols
\usepackage{bm}% Extra bold faces
% Define semibold shape for typewriter family
{\ttfamily}
\DeclareFontShape{\encodingdefault}{\ttdefault}{sb}{n}{<->ssub*\ttdefault/b/n}{}
\usepackage{soul} % For increased spacing of capitals and small caps
```

However, there are several other Times-like packages in wide sense, most notably [Tex Gyre Termes](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/tgtermes/) and the recently released [STIX](http://www.stixfonts.org/) package for latex. Which times-like package does a better job for typesetting text and math in latex, i.e. better typography, more symbols, matching math script fonts? I am specially interesetd in modern vesrions like Time New Roman and even lighter derivatives like Linux Libertine with more complete set of weights and shapes. A similar question was asked [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79863/what-is-going-on-with-all-these-times-clones). Should I keep using `newtx` or switch to a newer package like `STIX`?

P.S. `boondoxo` font package provides both *lowercase* and *uppercase* calligraphic math symbols as well as their *bold* versions.

Comment: If you load the `libertine` package and the `newtxmath` package with the `libertine` option, you won't get a `Times`-like text and math fonts but, well, `Linux Libertine`-like fonts. For a non-comprehensive review of the looks of various font families -- including several `Times`-like fonts -- that have both text and math font groups, you may want to check out http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59706/5001.

Comment: If you are interested in achieving better line-breaking and interword spacing, I would recommend that you check out the [`microtype`](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf) package. It allows you to customize various aspects of your fonts.

Comment: @Mico, thanks. For some people Linux Libertine is Times! because I changed `ptm` to `libertine` in university thesis style, and they did not complain. I personally prefer libertine because it is slightly lighter and still formal. For matchning math symbols, `newtx` does a good job. It uses the same math symbols for other times-like fonts. My question is, is it possible to get better typesetting from other times-like font packages? Are open-type math fonts such as STIX have better metrics? ...

Comment: @void-pointer thanx. I use `microtype`. And I have `T1` encoding.

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "times-like"? You are not using it in a way I understand and I gather from the comments that I'm not alone. This isn't meant as a criticism - it is just that "times-like" in this context usually means something like a substitute for times, a font which is or looks very like times, and perhaps also has the same metrics. But that wouldn't include Libertine which doesn't look much like times. So obviously you have something else in mind.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I may ask "what is the best way to typeset in Linux Libertine?" But I am not limitted to Libertine. IMO, Libertine was designed to replace Times in open community, I would name it Times Light Neue. May be I am too loose here! Anyway, a modern Times with matching math will also suit the purpose. MathTime Pro offers a good package, whioch I am not ready to buy now, and the setup above with Libertine and newtx suits my purpose. The question is that, which set of packages provide a typographically-pleasing typeset in times-libertine spectra?

Comment: Note that, matchning math symbols, different weights and shapes including small caps, and detailed metrics for TeX are of interest here, since there are many well designed fonts out there.

Comment: You were pointed by Mico to his answer. In my eyes your question is either a duplicate of this or must be closed as opinion-based, because there are indeed several good choices possible.

Comment: @Speravir, Mico's answer is great, but it covers a wide range with little details, and some of those packages render a poor text. I asked for Times-Libertine looks and matching symbols with typographical details, specifically for Tex Gyre Termes and STIX fonts which are not covered in that list. It might be opinion-based, but I need to know experts' opinion, which is typesetting rules. Unfortunately, many font packages do not have correct metrics, especially when typesetting math. That's why some people abondoned Latex.