# Migration from Computer Modern to Times New Roman fonts

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

I had typed my LaTeX article using `Computer Modern` fonts. Now I want Times New Roman and double spacing. I'm getting so many errors regarding font packages. Please help.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[auth-sc]{authblk}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\textwidth=13cm
```

Comment: `fontspec` requires xe- or lualatex as a compilation engine (not pdflatex), which in turn forces you to use unicode encoding and are incompatible with `inputenc`. So remove the `inputenc` line and compile with `lualatex`,

Comment: still getting the same errors

Comment: is there a way of getting times new roman without using fontspec package so that i dont have to make any other changes in my file.

Comment: You are doing too many font things and they are incompatible.  If you don't like `fontspec`, get rid of it (and the `\setmainfont`) and use a 'Times-like' font: [TeX Gyre Terms](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/tgtermes/), [newtx](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/newtx/), [mathptmx](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/times/), or [Nimbus Roman](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/nimbus/).  With any of these, keep `fontenc` and `inputenc` and compile with `latex` or `pdflatex`.

Comment: If you want to stay with pdfLaTeX, use packages such as `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` to make Times Roman the default text and math font family.

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of closing this question, here is a summary of the comments:

> `fontenc` and `inputenc` are incompatible with `fontspec`.

### `fontspec` with `xe`- / `lualatex`

`fontspec` lets you use any TrueType and OpenType font easily (with commands like `\setmainsfont` that just need the name of the font you want to use), but require you to compile your document with a modern TeX engine such as `xelatex` or `lualatex`. These two engines in return forces you to use `utf8` encoding, and are therefore incompatible with `\inputenc`. Also, as `fontspec` is a kinda upgrade to `fontenc`, you shouldn't load `fontenc` either.
For more information on `xelatex` / `lualatex` vs `pdflatex`, read these questions:

- [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2984/10102)
- [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28642/10102)

### `fontenc` with `pdflatex`

If for some reason you want or need to compile with the legacy `pdflatex`, you will need to find a font that is available in Type1 format, and load it "the old way".

The best option seem to be [TeX Gyre Termes](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/tgtermes/), loaded by the `tgtermes` package. Part of the modern [TeX Gyre](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tex-gyre/) collection of fonts, an initiative aimed at providing high quality versions of standard fonts for TeX and in OpenType format, it is a replacement for the older [URW Nimbus Roman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimbus_Roman_No9_L) font, that can be loaded by the `mathptmx` package (AFAIK, `mathptmx` is `nimbus` with math support added, but I might be wrong).

Another option is the [New TX](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/newtx/) font, loaded by the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages (you need to load both).

Note that for both these options you should also switch to [Cork font encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cork_encoding), i.e. `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

For more about Times replacement, you can read [What is going on with all these Times clones?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79866/10102)