# Command \maketitle with cyrillic and Times New Roman

Tags: xetex, babel, times

I am trying to output the title of the document using font Times New Roman with Bulgarian language. If I use

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bulgarian]{babel}

\title{Моят проект}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I get the error "! Corrupted NFSS tables".

If I change the position of the packages `fontspec` and `content` like this

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bulgarian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\title{Моят проект}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

I get the error "! LaTeX Error: Command \cyrg unavailable in encoding EU1".

Using the second example I am able to write in the body of the document in cyrillic, but commands like `\maketitle` and `\tableofcontents` does not work, leading to the aforementioned error (second example).

I am building using XeLaTeX.

Comment: Don't load `fontenc`.

Comment: I load it so that I can use \setmainfont. Is there an alternative to set the font Times New Roman globally for the whole document?

Comment: I said `fontenc`, not `fontspec`! Also you shouldn't load `inputenc` either.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Removing fontenc actually produces the same error: "! LaTeX Error: Command \cyrya unavailable in encoding EU1."

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125086/migration-from-computer-modern-to-times-new-roman-fonts

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately using the suggestion leas to too many problems with the whole document formatting, which means that I will have to rewrite the whole styling in order to make it work with newtxtext.

Comment: Why should you use `newtxtext`?

Comment: Can you please provide an example that I can use to be able to write in cyrillic using Times New Roman?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compile this file with either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, you'll get Times as main font. The packages `fontenc` and `inputenc` should not be loaded (see [Migration from Computer Modern to Times New Roman fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125086/migration-from-computer-modern-to-times-new-roman-fonts))

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[bulgarian]{babel}

\title{Моят проект}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

% The following text is from Wikipedia

София е столицата и най-големият град в България. Тя е 15-ят по големина град в Европейския 
съюз с население 1\,291\,591 души към преброяване 2011, което представлява 16,4\% от 
населението на България. Разположена е в централната част на Западна България, в 
Софийската котловина, заобиколена от планината Витоша на юг, планината Люлин на запад и 
Стара планина на север. Общата ѝ площ е 1344 квадратни километра, а средната ѝ надморска 
височина e около 580 метра. Това я прави четвъртата по височина столица в Европа. Изградена 
е върху четирите тераси на река Искър и притоците ѝ Перловска и Владайска (Елешница). В 
централната градска част, както и в кварталите Овча купел, Княжево, Горна баня и Панчарево, 
има минерални извори. Климатът на София е умереноконтинентален.

Тя е основен административен, индустриален, транспортен, културен и университетски център на 
страната, като в нея е съсредоточено 1/6 от промишленото производство на България. Тук се 
намират също така Българската академия на науките, много университети, театри, кина, както и 
Националната художествена галерия, археологически, исторически, природонаучни и други музеи. 
София носи името на късноантичната катедрала на града "Света София". Това се допълва от 
всенародната почит към светата мъченица София, майка на трите свети мъченици – Вяра, Надежда 
и Любов, и тъй като "Божествената премъдрост", т.е. Христос, е предмет на постоянно 
преклонение, неподвластно на определен ден от годината, то празникът на светиците - 17 
септември, е приет за Ден на София, чества се и 4 януари, когато градът е освободен от 
турско робство през 1878 г. от руските войски. София е обявена за столица на 3 април 1879 
година от Учредителното събрание по предложение на проф. Марин Дринов, като стар български 
град, отдалечен от турската граница и средищно разположен в българските земи според 
тогавашното разбиране.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The given example works for me with one problem only - when I generate it, the text is outputted, but the title's date does not show the month because of this error "! Undefined control sequence.
\month@bulgarian ->\ifcase \month \or \cyrya
\cyrn \cyru \cyra \cyrr \cyri \...
l.10 \maketitle"

Comment: @o15a3d4l11s2 You probably have to update your TeX distribution. Instead of loading `babel` you can do `\usepackage{polyglossia}\setmainlanguage{bulgarian}` (this only if you use XeLaTeX).

Comment: I have TeXLive 2013, also checked the babel -> 3.9f. Using polyglossia helped. Thanks a lot for the time and the efforts.